# Passing the "this" from the onclick event into the JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to remove the `onclick=togglePass(this)` from my anchor tag and want to use this in jQuery. I am confused how I can send `this` as a parameter to jQuery's?

`$('elem').click(function());`

Right now I am trying to replace the `onclick` with the following:

`$('elem').click(function(){..Some code..});`

But not sure how to pass the `this`.

Comment: `this` should be the DOM element within `click()` handler. Are you trying to set `this` to a different value within the event handler when the event is dispatched?

Comment: You don't have to because `this` inside the handler will refer to the element

Comment: so, if i am trying to replace the inline onclick method with the external jquery like $('#elm').click(function(){..some code..}); then do i need to send the argument to the jquery method or not?

Answer (score 5):

You do not need to pass `this` explicitly. 
`this` is automatically bound to the element implicitly on which the event is triggered.

Try the following example:

```js
$(".elem").click(function(){
  // this referes to the currently clicked element
  $(this).toggleClass('blue');
});
```

```css
.elem{
  background: green;
  width: 200px;
  height:200px;
  border-radius: 3px;
}
.blue{
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="elem">Container</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to pass **this** in jquery. Hope the example helps you.

```js
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".red").click(function(){
            $(this).toggleClass("green");
        });
    });
```

```css
.red{
background: red;
width: 100px;
height:100px;
}
.red.green{
background: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="red"></div>
click to change the color
```

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/click/) is not currently specific as to what `this` is within the function that is set as the event handler. The first argument at the function should be the jQuery event.

```
function fn(_this, e) { 
  console.log(
    _this /* event */
    , this /* `HTMLParagraphElement`
    , `e` : `undefined` */
  ) 
}

$("p").on("click", fn);
```

You should not have to pass an additional argument to the function or `.on()`. `this` within the event handler should be the DOM element, not the jQuery object within the event handler. If you are expecting `this` to be the first argument of the handler you can use you can use `$.proxy()` which also provides a parameter to pass an argument to the function

```
function fn(_this, e) { 
  console.log(
    _this /* `[456]` */
    , this /* `{abc: 123}` `e` : `jQuery.Event` */
  ) 
}

$("p").on("click", $.proxy(fn, {abc:123}, [456]));
```